# Facebook Logout not Working with offline_access

Tags: facebook

I am trying to implement the Facebook Login and Logout in my website.
I am using the Facebook PHP SDK.

The code i am using is as follows :

Login

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => APP_ID,
                           'secret' => APP_SECRET
                           ));

    $param = array();
    $param["scope"] = array("email","offline_access","publish_stream");

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($param);
```

Logout

```
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

The problem is logout url is not being able to logout the facebook user.

When i remove the "offline_access" from the scope parameters the logout Url is working fine.

I have also implemented the above scope in the example.php file in the PHP SDK and the result was the same.

Can anyone provide any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my problem. After logging in from Facebook I called the function `$facebook->destroySession();` and after that, called the function    `$facebook->getLogoutUrl();`.

Because of the `destroySession()` function the `access_token` returned from Facebook got lost and my logout URL generated from the `getLogoutUrl()` function could not log out the user from Facebook.

After removing the `destroySession()` function my code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are not clearing the session cookie after you log the user out of FB.

```
1) download the latest php sdk.
2) Make sure you specify the 'domain' parameter when you create the $facebook object.
3) Before you redirect the user to FB logout, clear their session with 
$facebook->setSession(null);  - alternatively, you can use FB.logout() in the javascript SDK.
```

Update:
as you are specifying appId and key, also give 'domain' as your domain name.

Examples of setSession:
[example1](http://sambro.is-super-awesome.com/2010/05/28/facebook-access-tokens-from-canvas-apps/)

Comment: Hello Somnath,
Thank You for your support.
I downloaded the latest php sdk.
facebook-php-sdk-v3.1.1-25-g6c82b3f.zip.

In the src folder there are 2 php pages.
But in either of the pages i could not find a function named setSession().

Also can you show me a sample use domain parameter when creaing the $facebook object.

By the way i think that i will not need the "offline_access" in the scope array.
But it would be nice if i could solve this error.

Regards,
Sourav